# About Intel speed select

Tags: kernel, drivers, intel

I am studying intel speed select:

official info:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/speed-select-technology-article.html

reference site:

https://www.tweaktown.com/articles/8953/intel-launches-cascade-lake-cpus-up-56-cores/index3.html

"reducing the frequency for low priority jobs to maintain high frequency on a high priority job"

In my understanding, Linux already can set different freq to different core.

and Linux (OS) also know each task's expected freq ( heavy loading or light loading, ex: load a web page or print one line log ), OS should able to do this kind of tech ( Intel speed select ) already.

Does Linux support this kind of feature (but not the intel speed select) in the kernel already?

What's the new in Intel speed select and linux kernel? ( in my understanding, kernel will support Intel speed select )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be emulated:

https://github.com/intel/CommsPowerManagement/blob/master/sst_bf.md

section **Emulating SST-BF**

If a suitable BIOS or Linux kernel is not available on the platform, SST-BF may be emulated by setting the min and max frequencies high on some of the cores. Typically this would be 6 or 8 cores at 2.7Ghz, and the remainder of the cores at 2.1GHz on a 20 core CPU.

Comment: what is the difference between emulating and kernel+bios support ?